# AWS Glue ETL and PySpark and partitioned data: how to create a dataframe column from partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have data in an S3 bucket containing many json-files that looks somewhat like this:

```
s3://bucket1/news/year=2018/month=01/day=01/hour=xx/
```

The `day` partition contains multiple `hour=xx` partitions, one for each hour of the day. I run a Glue ETL job on the files in the `day` partition and create a Glue `dynamic_frame_from_options`. I then apply some mapping using `ApplyMapping.apply` which works like a charm.

However, I would then like to create a new column, containing the `hour` value, based on the partition of each file. I can use Spark to create a new column with a constant, however, how do I make this column to use the partition as a source?

```
df1 = dynamicFrame.toDF().withColumn("update_date", lit("new column value"))
```

**Edit1**

The article from AWS on how to use partitioned data uses a Glue crawler before the creation of a dynamicFrame and then create the `dynamicFrame` from a Glue catalog. I need to create the `dynamicFrame` directly from the S3 source.
[enter link description here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/)

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/

Comment: Thank you, I have seen the article, however, they are using a Glue crawler before the creation of a dynamicFrame and then create the `dynamicFrame` from a Glue catalog. I need to create the `dynamicFrame` directly from the S3 source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really following what you need to do. Dont you already have a `hour` value if you have the files partitoned on it or is that only when you use `create_dynamic_frame .from_catalog` that you will get it?
Can you do a `df1["hour"]` or `df1.select_fields["hour"]`?

You do not need to import any libs if you have your data partitoned on `ts(timestamp in yyyymmddhh format)`, this you can perform with pure python in Spark.

Example code. First I create some values that will populate my DataFrame.
Then create a new variable like below.

```
df_values = [('2019010120',1),('2019010121',2),('2019010122',3),('2019010123',4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_values,['yyyymmddhh','some_other_values'])
df_new = df.withColumn("hour", df["yyyymmddhh"][9:10])
df_new.show()
+----------+-----------------+----+
|yyyymmddhh|some_other_values|hour|
+----------+-----------------+----+
|2019010120|                1|  20|
|2019010121|                2|  21|
|2019010122|                3|  22|
|2019010123|                4|  23|
+----------+-----------------+----+
```

Comment: This does unfortunately not work because the 'hour' column is empty when reading from options. That is my issue.

Comment: What do you want to populate hour with? What hour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AWS Glue, if the given link doesn't work for your case, then you can try and see if the following workaround works for you:

Get the file name using [input_file_name](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name), then use `regexp_extract` to get the partition column you want from the file name:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name, regexp_extract

df2 = df1.withColumn("hour", regexp_extract(input_file_name(), "hour=(.+?)/", 1))
```

Comment: This would work great, however, the input_file_name is only available if the `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog ` function is used to create the dynamic frame. I need to create from S3 data `create_dynamic_frame_from_options`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem you would like to build dataframe for given day with the hours as partitions. Generally if you use Apache Hive-style partitioned paths and your files have the same schema you shouldn't have a problem to use

```
ds = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    's3',
    {'paths': ['s3://bucket1/news/year=2018/month=01/day=01/']},
    'json')
```

or...

```
df = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").json('s3://bucket1/news/year=2018/month=01/day=01/')
```

So if it doesn't work you should check whether you use Apache Hive-style partitioned paths and your files have the same schema.

You can also try to use boto3 framework in Glue (it may be useful to you) :

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Useful link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Comment: This looks great. However, I need the partitions inside the `path` `['s3://bucket1/news/year=2018']`, so I use the `recursive=true` flag. Then, the partitions do not appear in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

> "...AWS Glue does not include the partition columns in the DynamicFrame—it only includes the data."

We have to load the S3 key into a new column and decode the partitions programatically to create the columns we want into the Dynamic Frame/Data Frame.
Once created, we can use them as we need.

ps: I have test it against parquet files. It doesn't work for JSON files.

[Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-unable-to-infer-schema/)